# Delete tuples from SQL db

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to do the following homework,
I have 3 tables, respectively:

```
TblNation with fields: id_nation (key), first nation, second nation
TblAthlete with fields: id_athlete (key), name, surname
TblUnion with fields: id_nation (key), id_athlete(key)
```

I have to delete the tuple corresponding to a specific surname (it's supposed that there is no redundancy of surname field).

I have tried:

```
DELETE FROM TblNation INNER JOIN
    TblUnion ON TblNation.id_Nation = 
    TblUnion.id_nation INNER JOIN
    TblAthlete ON TblUnion.id_athlete = TblAthlete.id_athlete
WHERE TblAthlete.surname = 'something'
```

But this code doesn't work...can anyone help me please?

ps. I'm trying to run this query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question and you will more than likely get a quicker, *correct* answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you mean that you need to see the content of tables?

Comment: Content or sample content would be helpful. As it stands your query should work, however, with the use of the inner joins you may be excluding rows that you expect to be included.

Comment: As it stands SQL Server doesn't know which table to delete the rows from.  @Gofr1's answer below shows the correct syntax.  If you get stuck again take a peek at the docs over on [Microsoft's Developer Network (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189835.aspx).  The documentation almost always includes a working example, which can be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DELETE T
FROM TblNation T
INNER JOIN TblUnion TU
    ON T.id_Nation = TU.id_nation
INNER JOIN TblAthlete TA
    ON TU.id_athlete = TA.id_athlete
WHERE TA.surname = 'something'
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you understand why you'd want to write a three-table join just to delete rows out of a single table...

Based on the criteria you stated (*I have to delete the tuple corresponding to a specific surname*), why don't you just delete from `TblAthlete` with fields  `id_athlete` (key), name, surname?

```
BEGIN TRAN
  DELETE from TblAthlete 
   WHERE surname = 'something';
COMMIT
```